# How would I negate "I used to be able to do it"?

Tags: negation, used-to

i)

> "I used to be able to do it."

What's the negative form of the abovementioned sentence? Is it natural to say - "I used to be able to not do it."?

ii)

is there any grammatical (like punctuation) error in (i)

Comment: For the negative, I'd say "I used to be unable to do it."

Comment: 'Use[d] to' and 'be able to' are semi-modals; putting the two together multiplies complicating factors. 'I used to be able to do it' may mean either 'Once, I had mastered the art / skill ... of doing it and so had the competence to do it' (epistemic modality) **or** 'Once, I was permitted to do it' (deontic modality).So 'I used to be able to not do it' can mean either ''Once, I had the skill ... to be able to avoid doing it' **or** 'Once, I was permitted to not do it'. But note that 'be able not to ...' is the usual ordering. //// 'I wasn't once able to do it' sounds more idiomatic.

Comment: @nnnnnn said "I used to be unable to do it".  Or perhaps "I used to be able to not do it" is intended to mean "I used to be able to resist doing it."

Comment: What are you trying to express with the negation?

Comment: @Lawrence I wanted to mean something like 'I have learned something new. I couldn't do it in the past.'

Comment: "I couldn't do it before" would be fine. "I used to be unable to do it" is pretty much the same meaning, but slightly more formal. "I was previously unable to do it" is what you'd write in a business letter.

Comment: I (British, 60+) would say "I used not to be able to do it". Checking this on Google, I found [this thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/didnt-use-to-used-not-to.2449804/)

Comment: @KateBunting That is just English. Also: I used to not be able to do it.

Comment: You are on the wrong site for this sort of question as is clearly stated in the Tour. English Language Learners is where you should try.

Comment: @David thanks for the info. I didn't know as I'm new on the platform. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

One answer is

> I didn't use(d) to be able to do it.

It is spelled both with and without the "d", and [people argue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/whats-the-negation-of-i-used-to-be-surely-not-i-didnt-used-to-be) over which way is grammatical, but the pronunciation is the same for both cases.

Comment: This is the right answer. These work-rounds are all very well, but in real English, that people speak, the negative of _I used to_ is _I didn't use(d) to_.